# Spring attribute concatenating attributes values followed by commas

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

In below code, I am geeting list and view correctly but while updating I am facing only first field rsoCode concatenated e.g. if my rsoCode is **NH43** then it will comes to controller as **NH43,NH43**. In the update form it displays correctly but when it comes to

While debug I have observed that the getRsoCode() invoked twice while coming to update screen(where we can change the values).

This is JSP code

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<form:form action="" method="POST" commandName="updateRso">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold; font-variant: small-caps;">RSO Code:</td>
        <td><form:input path="rsoCode" value="${updateRso.rsoCode}" disabled="disabled"/></td></tr>

    <tr><td style="font-weight: bold; font-variant: small-caps;">RSO Description:</td>
        <td><form:input path="rsoDescriprion" value="${updateRso.rsoDescriprion}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold; font-variant: small-caps;">Region Code:</td>
        <td><form:input path="regionCode" value="${updateRso.regionCode}"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td style="font-weight: bold; font-variant: small-caps;">Region Description:</td>
        <td><form:input path="regiondescription" value="${updateRso.regiondescription}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Submit"/> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
```

**Controller Code**

```
@Controller
public class ListRsoController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ListRsoController.class);

    @ModelAttribute("updateRso")
    public ListRso getListRso()
    {

        ListRso updateRso = new ListRso();

        return updateRso;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="listrso")
    public String listAllRso(ModelMap model) throws Exception{

        ListRsoDao listDao = new ListRsoDao();

        model.addAttribute("rsos", listDao.getList());

        return "listrso/view";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="getRsoDetails")
    public String getRso(@RequestParam("rsoCode")String rsoCode, ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception{

        ListRsoDao lstdto = new ListRsoDao();

        Object obj = lstdto.getRsoCode(rsoCode);

        model.addAttribute("savedClass", obj);

        return "listrso/viewdetails";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="updateRsoDetails", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateRso(@RequestParam("rsoCode")String rsoCode, ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception{

        ListRsoDao lstdto = new ListRsoDao();

        Object obj = lstdto.getRsoCode(rsoCode);

        model.addAttribute("updateRso", obj);

        return "listrso/updatedetails";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="deleteRsoDetails")
    public String deleteRso(@RequestParam("rsoCode")ListRso rsoCode, ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception{

        ListRsoDao lstdto = new ListRsoDao();

        lstdto.deleteRso(rsoCode);

        //model.addAttribute("savedClass", obj);

        return "listrso/deleteSuccess";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="updateRsoDetails")
    protected String onSubmit( @ModelAttribute("updateRso") ListRso rsoCommand,  ModelMap model ) throws Exception
    {
        model.clear();
        new  ListRsoDao().updateRso(rsoCommand);
        model.addAttribute("savedClass", rsoCommand);
        return "listrso/view";
    }

}
```

Java Bean

```
public class ListRso {

    private String rsoCode;
    private String rsoDescriprion;
    private String regionCode;
    private String regiondescription;

    public ListRso(String rsoCode, String rsoDescriprion, String regionCode,
            String regiondescription) {
        super();
        this.rsoCode = rsoCode;
        this.rsoDescriprion = rsoDescriprion;
        this.regionCode = regionCode;
        this.regiondescription = regiondescription;
    }

    public ListRso(String rsoCode)
    {
        this.rsoCode = rsoCode;
    }
    public ListRso() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public String getRsoCode() {
        return rsoCode;
    }
    public void setRsoCode(String rsoCode) {
        this.rsoCode = rsoCode;
    }
    public String getRsoDescriprion() {
        return rsoDescriprion;
    }
    public void setRsoDescriprion(String rsoDescriprion) {
        this.rsoDescriprion = rsoDescriprion;
    }
    public String getRegionCode() {
        return regionCode;
    }
    public void setRegionCode(String regionCode) {
        this.regionCode = regionCode;
    }
    public String getRegiondescription() {
        return regiondescription;
    }
    public void setRegiondescription(String regiondescription) {
        this.regiondescription = regiondescription;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no action for your form this causes spring tags to [do weird stuff](http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2009/02/springs-form-tags-make-sure-you-set.html).
And this  :

```
<form:form action="" method="POST" commandName="updateRso">
```

means you only need to do this (remove the value attribute, the input is populated from path)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold; font-variant: small-caps;">RSO Code:</td>
        <td><form:input path="rsoCode" disabled="disabled"/></td>
```

Comment: I have tried above solution but still it is not working. While debuging I have observed that getRsoCode called twice while redering update details screen I mean the screen where one can change the values of the data

Comment: In list I have seen view source code on the page, it is populating at once but update page it is populating twice  and how it is adding comma and concat these values

Comment: @Kamahire what does ListRsoDao return ? You need to change all the form elements to reference only path as well.

Comment: it is simple java code where I am writing update query, insert and delete query

Comment: No, what object does it return when you call it : lstdto.getRsoCode(rsoCode); You have just referenced it as Object

Comment: ListRsoDao return ListRso bean object basically object of cjava bean class having getter and setter method.

Comment: @Kamahire you need to specify action in your form

Comment: Thanks! Save my day! :)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have came across similar issue
Root cause of the issue was that I have defined same path variable twice one visible on the screen and the other one was hidden. While submitting the form it was concatinating value with same path/name by commqnd.
To fix this you have remove the hidden one.

Hope this information helps